# How can i get a files Id on Onedrive using the graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have a file that i know exists in one drive , TestFile.xlxs.It sits in the folder
Folder1/SubFolder2/SubFolder 2a/.  I am trying t get the fileId as follows, so i can move the file to another folder in OneDrive

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Folder1/SubFolder2/SubFolder 2a/TestFile.xlsx
```

but i get the error

```
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Empty Payload. JSON content expected.",
```

Any ideas how i can get the id of the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you did `POST` request instead of `GET`.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Folder1/SubFolder2/SubFolder 2a/TestFile.xlsx
```

`POST` request will probably work if you add empty json into the request body.

```
{}
```